# USB OTG device that always supplies +5V, any issues?

Tags: usb, usb-device

I recently came across an USB device that seems to have a broken USB OTG implementation. The device always provides +5V on its micro-USB port, and using the appropriate adapter, you can use other USB clients (storage etc.). It's not powered through the USB port, but rather with a proprietary charger. So far, so good.

However, even if you plug in a regular micro-USB cable with a plain old USB-A plug for connecting to a host, it still provides +5V. This is obviously wrong according to the spec, but will it actually cause any issues?

AFAICT it should be fine: both the host and the device drive the supply line to +5V, but since neither side actually draws power from the connection, it will basically just stay there. I'm guessing that the voltages won't be exactly equal (maybe +4.98V and +5.03V or so), therefore a few mA might flow from one side to the other, but this is something that the protection circuit inside the port should be able to handle?

Comment: That's a non-compliant device.  "since neither side actually draws power from the connection, it will basically just stay there" - you can't say that.  What happens for example if one is unplugged from its usual power source or that is unplugged?  And you don't know what protection devices are or are not present.  Ultimately, questions about the usage of products are not on topic here.

Comment: I know it's definitely violating the standard. I was rather wondering if the standard specifies e.g. which protection circuit should be present and what it should be rated for? But you raise an excellent point regarding what happens when the power is out on one side...